# How to rotated and span a large table over 2 pages?

Tags: tables, longtable, landscape

For my Thesis i need to inlude a table with 25 portfolios.

I was able to rotate the page, however to make it more readable it would be best if the lowest two section would continue ont he next page.
I tried to use \begin{longtable} but it's not working.

Does someone have a idea?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}



\afterpage{
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{ccclclcclrlrrlrlrrlrlrrlrl}
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1.1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{292} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1.2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 337 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1.3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 366 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1.4}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 327 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 359 &  \\
        & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Corrado Test} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-5} & 0.000\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.580} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.655} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.264\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.1980} &     & 0.1095 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.558\%} & -2.100 & **  & -2.166 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.203\%} & 0.684 &     & 0.431 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.153\%} & 0.6530 &     & 1.0161 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-4} & -1.135\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.849} & *   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.099} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & -0.212\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.3415} &     & -0.2107 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.247\%} & 0.320 &     & 0.394 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.094\%} & -0.234 &     & 0.321 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.382\%} & 1.0119 &     & 0.5596 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-3} & -0.115\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.419} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.661} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.617\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.1973} &     & -1.7026 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.385\%} & -0.787 &     & -1.101 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.376\%} & -0.373 &     & -1.177 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.083\%} & -0.4750 &     & -0.8070 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-2} & 0.244\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.447} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.596} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.062\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.4925} &     & -0.7548 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.017\%} & -0.309 &     & -0.266 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.881\%} & 0.920 &     & 0.990 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.165\%} & 0.3877 &     & 0.2975 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-1} & -0.482\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.535} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.405} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.887\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.4222} &     & -1.9085 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.277\%} & 0.864 &     & 0.719 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.401\%} & -0.614 &     & -1.274 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.524\%} & -0.4793 &     & -0.6727 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=0} & -1.115\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.116} & **  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.318} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & -1.493\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.1289} & *** & -3.1177 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.273\%} & -2.918 & *** & -2.485 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.555\%} & -1.209 &     & -1.638 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.616\%} & -1.3734 &     & -1.2371 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=1} & -0.495\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.669} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.992} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.309\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.4984} &     & -0.3547 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.860\%} & -2.054 & **  & -1.933 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.352\%} & -1.081 &     & -1.334 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.519\%} & -1.6522 & *   & -2.7110 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=2} & -0.710\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.163} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.146} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.145\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.1485} &     & -0.4728 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.875\%} & -1.935 & *   & -1.902 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.411\%} & -0.039 &     & 0.121 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.267\%} & 0.1748 &     & 0.0997 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=3} & -0.342\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.323} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.400} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.530\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.6798} &     & -1.2340 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.637\%} & 1.746 & *   & 1.853 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.243\%} & 0.968 &     & 1.198 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.052\%} & -0.0750 &     & 0.1614 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=4} & 0.504\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.559} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.328} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.539\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.5010} &     & 1.2036 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.115\%} & -0.198 &     & 0.104 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.260\%} & -0.489 &     & -1.347 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.292\%} & -0.1191 &     & -1.0051 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=5} & 0.057\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.044} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.113} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.334\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.2017} &     & -0.2486 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.096\%} & 0.314 &     & 0.456 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.292\%} & -0.799 &     & -0.706 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.527\%} & 0.9427 &     & 0.6138 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,1)} & -1.610\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.456} & **  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.122} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & -1.802\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.1488} & *** & -2.4675 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.133\%} & -4.181 & *** & -3.412 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.906\%} & -1.917 & *   & -1.934 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.135\%} & -2.4604 & **  & -2.0202 & ** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,2)} & -2.320\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.998} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.337} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & -1.946\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.2157} & *** & -2.3403 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-3.007\%} & -5.243 & *** & -3.947 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.495\%} & -1.975 & **  & -1.357 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.868\%} & -2.2250 & **  & -1.4954 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,3)} & -2.662\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.523} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.343} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.476\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.6533} & *** & -2.5696 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.370\%} & -4.318 & *** & -2.552 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.252\%} & -1.505 &     & -0.335 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.920\%} & -2.1720 & **  & -1.4584 &  \\
    \midrule
    \midrule
                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{3.1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{314} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{3.2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 331 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{3.3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 344 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{3.4}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 345 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{3.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 342 &  \\
        & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Corrado Test} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-5} & -0.057\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.297} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.321} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.075\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.048} &     & -0.012 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.284\%} & -0.544 &     & -0.407 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.152\%} & -0.120 &     & 0.054 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.105\%} & 0.616 &     & 0.696 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-4} & -0.401\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.530} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.281} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.018\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.218} &     & 0.550 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.048\%} & 0.112 &     & -0.106 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.315\%} & 0.643 &     & 0.747 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.217\%} & 0.711 &     & 0.894 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-3} & -0.790\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.211} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.455} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -1.178\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.516} & **  & -2.659 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.753\%} & -1.424 &     & -1.850 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.236\%} & -0.789 &     & -0.988 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.519\%} & -1.810 & *   & -1.991 & ** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-2} & -0.167\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.348} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.441} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.067\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.140} &     & 0.082 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.074\%} & 0.045 &     & 0.069 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.427\%} & -1.072 &     & -0.866 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.238\%} & 0.792 &     & 0.872 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-1} & -0.165\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.371} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.069} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.362\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.870} &     & -0.942 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.155\%} & -0.417 &     & -0.150 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.041\%} & -0.255 &     & -0.688 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.152\%} & 0.333 &     & 0.271 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=0} & -2.360\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.125} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.634} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -1.557\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.339} & *** & -3.486 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.432\%} & -3.420 & *** & -3.727 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.981\%} & -2.967 & *** & -3.124 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.170\%} & -3.732 & *** & -4.007 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=1} & -0.995\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.811} & *   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.768} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & -0.805\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.456} &     & -1.701 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.513\%} & -1.286 &     & -1.421 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.689\%} & -1.898 & *   & -2.040 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.318\%} & -0.797 &     & -1.098 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=2} & -0.209\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.430} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.412} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.094\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.099} &     & 0.059 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.207\%} & -0.477 &     & -0.233 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.297\%} & 0.639 &     & 0.745 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.362\%} & -0.959 &     & -1.204 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=3} & 0.423\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.809} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.904} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.311\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.405} &     & 0.750 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.510\%} & 1.116 &     & 1.686 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.289\%} & 0.916 &     & 0.839 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.473\%} & 1.203 &     & 1.240 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=4} & 0.397\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.783} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.794} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.118\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.255} &     & -0.139 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.003\%} & -0.020 &     & -0.008 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.138\%} & 0.091 &     & -0.042 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.083\%} & 0.274 &     & 0.273 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=5} & -0.412\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.565} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.634} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.347\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.698} &     & 0.420 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.095\%} & -0.443 &     & -0.319 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.101\%} & 0.321 &     & 0.430 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.105\%} & 0.404 &     & 0.412 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,1)} & -3.356\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-5.009} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.329} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.363\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.139} & *** & -3.726 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.945\%} & -3.949 & *** & -3.538 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.671\%} & -4.131 & *** & -3.608 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.488\%} & -3.876 & *** & -3.429 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,2)} & -3.564\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.780} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.788} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.457\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.085} & *** & -2.917 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.151\%} & -3.777 & *** & -3.098 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.373\%} & -3.434 & *** & -2.613 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.850\%} & -3.981 & *** & -3.502 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,3)} & -3.142\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.260} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.801} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.146\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.517} & *** & -2.306 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.642\%} & -3.248 & *** & -1.799 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.084\%} & -2.806 & *** & -1.833 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.377\%} & -3.196 & *** & -2.385 & ** \\
    \midrule
    \midrule
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{4.1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{331} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{4.2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 367 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{4.3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 388 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{4.4}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 417 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{4.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 369 &  \\
        & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Corrado Test} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-5} & -0.030\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.051} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.158} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.094\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.493} &     & 0.466 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.117\%} & 0.426 &     & 0.264 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.159\%} & 0.503 &     & 0.495 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.185\%} & 0.812 &     & 0.696 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-4} & -0.824\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.096} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.137} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.028\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.043} &     & 0.058 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.118\%} & -0.003 &     & 0.147 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.209\%} & 0.915 &     & 0.984 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.286\%} & 0.903 &     & 0.745 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-3} & -0.909\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.550} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.682} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & -0.546\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.292} &     & -1.368 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.513\%} & -1.378 &     & -1.352 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.388\%} & -1.103 &     & -1.383 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.499\%} & -1.784 & *   & -1.812 & * \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-2} & 0.192\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.246} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.240} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.098\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.213} &     & 0.016 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.111\%} & 0.053 &     & 0.097 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.134\%} & 0.189 &     & 0.130 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.037\%} & 0.118 &     & 0.089 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-1} & 0.015\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.004} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.155} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.027\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.147} &     & 0.094 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.046\%} & -0.097 &     & -0.242 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.080\%} & -0.312 &     & -0.453 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.131\%} & -0.717 &     & -0.826 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=0} & -2.412\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.259} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.268} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -1.593\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.905} & *** & -3.371 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.292\%} & -2.573 & **  & -3.202 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.246\%} & -3.517 & *** & -3.689 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.395\%} & -3.470 & *** & -3.989 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=1} & -1.151\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.846} & *   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.898} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & -0.807\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.999} & **  & -2.186 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.463\%} & -1.420 &     & -1.680 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.221\%} & -0.775 &     & -0.878 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.305\%} & -0.977 &     & -0.948 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=2} & -0.858\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.430} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.358} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.494\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.812} &     & -0.765 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.284\%} & -0.556 &     & -0.526 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.150\%} & -0.489 &     & -0.525 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.333\%} & -0.833 &     & -0.652 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=3} & 0.755\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.872} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.202} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.942\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.934} & *   & 1.950 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.300\%} & 0.657 &     & 1.143 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.514\%} & 1.306 &     & 1.580 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.553\%} & 1.379 &     & 1.264 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=4} & -0.192\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.083} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.080} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.122\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.354} &     & -0.367 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.165\%} & 0.409 &     & 0.419 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.163\%} & -0.547 &     & -0.677 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.129\%} & -0.363 &     & -0.392 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=5} & 0.094\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.316} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.372} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.232\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.553} &     & 0.567 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.152\%} & 0.434 &     & 0.483 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.059\%} & 0.086 &     & 0.121 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.154\%} & 0.351 &     & 0.280 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,1)} & -3.563\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.873} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.356} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.399\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.985} & *** & -3.929 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.755\%} & -3.119 & *** & -3.393 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.466\%} & -3.559 & *** & -3.223 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.700\%} & -3.606 & *** & -3.393 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,2)} & -4.421\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.920} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.376} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.893\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.866} & *** & -3.594 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.039\%} & -3.071 & *** & -3.126 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.616\%} & -3.581 & *** & -2.941 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.034\%} & -3.785 & *** & -3.200 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,3)} & -3.666\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.083} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.206} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -1.951\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.932} & *** & -2.171 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.739\%} & -2.574 & **  & -2.119 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.102\%} & -2.970 & *** & -1.794 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.481\%} & -3.166 & *** & -2.065 & ** \\
    \midrule
    \midrule
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{5.1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{437} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{5.2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 466 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{5.3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 469 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{5.4}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 470 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{5.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 475 &  \\
        & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari Test} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Corrado Test} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-5} & 0.347\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.7954} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.9103} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.231\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.758} &     & 0.931 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.261\%} & 0.926 &     & 0.940 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.484\%} & 1.282 &     & 1.378 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.319\%} & 0.739 &     & 0.757 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-4} & -0.530\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.8836} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.8140} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.074\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.043} &     & 0.071 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.090\%} & 0.120 &     & 0.158 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.095\%} & 0.585 &     & 0.544 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.161\%} & 0.426 &     & 0.322 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-3} & -1.067\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.8923} & *   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.7895} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & -0.459\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.038} &     & -1.008 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.369\%} & -0.918 &     & -1.047 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.386\%} & -0.972 &     & -0.975 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.541\%} & -1.751 & *   & -2.002 & ** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-2} & 0.113\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.1599} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.0874} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.200\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.502} &     & 0.460 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.320\%} & 0.694 &     & 0.601 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.267\%} & 0.552 &     & 0.664 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.293\%} & 0.662 &     & 0.580 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-1} & 0.046\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.1383} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.0040} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.300\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.880} &     & -0.935 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.042\%} & 0.095 &     & -0.135 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.071\%} & -0.162 &     & -0.347 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.200\%} & -0.318 &     & -0.233 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=0} & -1.855\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.7370} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.6594} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -1.562\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.579} & *** & -3.841 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.453\%} & -3.651 & *** & -3.786 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.399\%} & -3.155 & *** & -3.624 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.437\%} & -3.140 & *** & -3.486 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=1} & -0.608\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.7882} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.9071} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.451\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.802} &     & -0.922 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.558\%} & -1.164 &     & -1.316 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.171\%} & -0.402 &     & -0.475 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.037\%} & 0.115 &     & 0.037 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=2} & -0.688\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.9848} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.9385} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.540\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.949} &     & -1.004 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.418\%} & -1.008 &     & -1.189 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.079\%} & -0.208 &     & -0.297 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.033\%} & 0.362 &     & 0.098 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=3} & 1.175\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.6189} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.9759} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & 1.006\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{2.116} & **  & 2.408 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.747\%} & 1.581 &     & 1.585 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.678\%} & 1.556 &     & 1.619 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.741\%} & 1.936 & *   & 2.177 & ** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=4} & 0.078\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.0290} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.1319} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.165\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.442} &     & -0.694 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.073\%} & -0.278 &     & -0.262 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.233\%} & -0.817 &     & -0.931 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.458\%} & -1.495 &     & -1.741 & * \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=5} & 0.527\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.1289} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.0164} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.274\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.814} &     & 0.710 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.316\%} & 0.857 &     & 0.865 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.351\%} & 1.022 &     & 1.104 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.134\%} & 0.552 &     & 0.518 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,1)} & -2.463\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.7047} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.2350} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.013\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.459} & *** & -3.365 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.011\%} & -3.906 & *** & -3.608 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.570\%} & -3.211 & *** & -2.882 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.473\%} & -2.912 & *** & -2.429 & ** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,2)} & -3.151\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.6286} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.1710} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.553\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.442} & *** & -3.327 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.429\%} & -3.901 & *** & -3.630 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.649\%} & -3.078 & *** & -2.514 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.440\%} & -2.139 & **  & -1.917 & * \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,3)} & -1.976\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.5754} & **  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.7547} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & -1.547\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.576} & *** & -1.686 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.682\%} & -3.246 & *** & -2.326 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.971\%} & -2.389 & **  & -1.397 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.699\%} & -1.351 &     & -0.580 &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{*** 1\% significance} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ ** 5\% significance} &     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{* 10\% significance} &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &  \\
    \end{tabular}}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
\clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you like to have long table over two page, than (i) you should not lockdown into `table` environment and should use `longtable` instead of tabular. Anyway, your table has huge width and cannot be fit on landscape page width.  (height in portrait orientation}. Also almost all `\multicolum` cells are superfluous, and vertical lines doesn't work well with `booktabs` rules.

Comment: @Zarko as you point it out it is a table with huge width and length. With the help of `\resizebox` i was able to place it on a page. However the numbers are small. Therefore i was looking for a combination of ratation and span it over multiple pages.

Comment: Don't use `resizebox`. If you will use, than you need to deliver to readers magnifying glas that they will able to read what you have in your table ;-)

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: What's the reason for placing the asterisks in a separate column?

Comment: Please clean up your code. The repeated use of `\multicolumn{1}...` is not necessary here and just makes your code harder to read.

Comment: Hi @leandriis, i organized my data in excel and exported it through excel2latex addon. The purpose of the separated column is to format it, aligning the commas. Thank you for your example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let extend my comment to an example how you can write your table. In example are used

- `xltabular` table environment instead `longtable
- `S` column types defined in `siunitx` package (similar as @leandriss in his answer: +1) with rounding option to three decimal digits
- `threeparttablex` package for table notes
- `changepage` package for local enlarge page width
- `small` fontsize

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelsep={colon},
            labelfont={bf},
            format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcr{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{r}{#2}}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{afterpage}
    
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\lipsum[1-7]

\afterpage{\clearpage%
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{\marginparsep}{-\dimexpr3\marginparsep}
\sisetup{table-format=-1.3,
         round-mode=places,
         round-precision=3}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt}
    \small%footnotesize
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
\item[*]    \SI{1}{\%}  significance,
\item[**]   \SI{5}{\%}  significance,
\item[***]  \SI{10}{\%} significance.
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}
         X 
    *{5}{S 
         S[table-space-text-post={***}]
         S[table-space-text-post={***}]}
                              @{}}
    \caption{Add caption}
    \label{fig:longtable}                                               \\
    \toprule
    & \mcc{\textbf{1.1}}
        & \mcc[2]{Observations 292}
                & \mcc{\textbf{1.2}}
                    & \mcc[2]{Observations 337}
                            & \mcc{\textbf{1.3}}
                                & \mcc[2]{Observations 366}
                                        & \mcc{\textbf{1.4}}
                                            & \mcc[2]{Observations 327}
                                                    & \mcc{\textbf{1.5}}
                                                        & \mcc[2]{Observations 359} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}
    \cmidrule(l){8-10}\cmidrule(l){11-13}\cmidrule(l){14-16}
    & \mcc{\makecell{AAR/\\ CAAR\\ (\%)}}
        & {\makecell{Kolari\\ Test}}
            & {\makecell{Corrado\\ Test}}
                & \mcc{\makecell{AAR/\\ CAAR\\ (\%)}}
                    & {\makecell{Kolari\\ Test}}
                        & {\makecell{Corrado\\ Test}}
                            & \mcc{\makecell{AAR/\\ CAAR\\ (\%)}}
                                & {\makecell{Kolari\\ Test}}
                                    & {\makecell{Corrado\\ Test}}
                                        & \mcc{\makecell{AAR/\\ CAAR\\ (\%)}}
                                            & {\makecell{Kolari\\ Test}}
                                                & {\makecell{Corrado\\ Test}}
                                                    & \mcc{\makecell{AAR/\\ CAAR\\ (\%)}}
                                                        & {\makecell{Kolari\\ Test}}
                                                            & {\makecell{Corrado\\ Test}} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Add caption} \\
    \toprule
    & \mcc{\textbf{1.1}}
        & \mcc[2]{Observations 292}
                & \mcc{\textbf{1.2}}
                    & \mcc[2]{Observations 337}
                            & \mcc{\textbf{1.3}}
                                & \mcc[2]{Observations 366}
                                        & \mcc{\textbf{1.4}}
                                            & \mcc[2]{Observations 327}
                                                    & \mcc{\textbf{1.5}}
                                                        & \mcc[2]{Observations 359} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}
    \cmidrule(l){8-10}\cmidrule(l){11-13}\cmidrule(l){14-16}
    & \mcc{\makecell{AAR/\\ CAAR}}
        & {\makecell{Kolari\\ Test}}
            & {\makecell{Corrado\\ Test}}
                & \mcc{\makecell{AAR/\\ CAAR}}
                    & {\makecell{Kolari\\ Test}}
                        & {\makecell{Corrado\\ Test}}
                            & \mcc{\makecell{AAR/\\ CAAR}}
                                & {\makecell{Kolari\\ Test}}
                                    & {\makecell{Corrado\\ Test}}
                                        & \mcc{\makecell{AAR/\\ CAAR}}
                                            & {\makecell{Kolari\\ Test}}
                                                & {\makecell{Corrado\\ Test}}
                                                    & \mcc{\makecell{AAR/\\ CAAR}}
                                                        & {\makecell{Kolari\\ Test}}
                                                            & {\makecell{Corrado\\ Test}} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \mcr[16]{\footnotesize{\textit{Continue on the next page}}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
AAR $t=-5$
    & -0.057    & -0.297            & -0.321
    & -0.075    & -0.048            & -0.012
    & -0.284    & -0.544            & -0.407
    & -0.152    & -0.120            &  0.054
    &  0.105    &  0.616            &  0.696            \\
AAR $t=-4$
    & -0.401    & -0.530            & -0.281
    &  0.018    &  0.218            &  0.550
    &  0.048    &  0.112            & -0.106
    &  0.315    &  0.643            &  0.747
    &  0.217    &  0.711            &  0.894            \\
AAR $t=-3$
    & -0.790    &  -1.211           & -1.455
    & -1.178    & -2.516\tnote{**}  & -2.659\tnote{***}
    & -0.753    & -1.424            & -1.850\tnote{*}
    & -0.236    & -0.789            & -0.988
    & -0.519    & -1.810\tnote{*}   & -1.991\tnote{**}    \\
AAR $t=-2$
    & -0.167    & -0.348            & -0.441
    & -0.067    & -0.140            &  0.082
    &  0.074    &  0.045            &  0.069
    & -0.427    & -1.072            & -0.866
    &  0.238    &  0.792            &  0.872             \\
AAR $t=-1$
    & -0.165    & -0.371            & -0.069
    & -0.362    & -0.870            & -0.942
    & -0.155    & -0.417            & -0.150
    & -0.041    & -0.255            & -0.688
    &  0.152    &  0.333            &  0.271            \\
AAR $t=0$
    & -2.360    & -4.125\tnote{***} & -4.634\tnote{***}
    & -1.557    & -3.339\tnote{***} & -3.486\tnote{***}
    & -1.432    & -3.420\tnote{***} & -3.727\tnote{***}
    & -0.981    & -2.967\tnote{***} & -3.124\tnote{***}
    & -1.170    & -3.732\tnote{***} & -4.007\tnote{***}   \\
    \addlinespace
AAR $t=1$
    & -0.995    & -1.811\tnote{*}   & -1.768\tnote{*}
    & -0.805    & -1.456            & -1.701\tnote{*}
    & -0.513    & -1.286            & -1.421
    & -0.689    & -1.898\tnote{*}   & -2.040\tnote{**}
    & -0.318    & -0.797            & -1.098            \\
AAR $t=2$
    & -0.209    & -0.430            & -0.412
    & -0.094    & -0.099            & 0.059
    & -0.207    & -0.477            & -0.233
    &  0.297    &  0.639            &  0.745
    & -0.362    & -0.959            & -1.204            \\
AAR $t=3$
    &  0.423    &  0.809            &  0.904
    &  0.311    &  0.405            &  0.750
    &  0.510    &  1.116            &  1.686\tnote{*}
    &  0.289    &  0.916            &  0.839
    &  0.473    &  1.203            &  1.240             \\
AAR $t=4$
    &  0.397    &  0.783            &  0.794
    &  0.118    &  0.255            & -0.139
    &  0.003    & -0.020            & -0.008
    &  0.138    &  0.091            & -0.042
    &  0.083    &  0.274            & 0.273             \\
AAR $t=5$
    & -0.412    & -0.565            & -0.634
    &  0.347    &  0.698            & 0.420
    & -0.095    & -0.443            & -0.319
    &  0.101    &  0.321            & 0.430
    &  0.105    &  0.404            & 0.412             \\
    \addlinespace
CAAR (0,1)
    & -3.356    & -5.009\tnote{***} & -4.329\tnote{***}
    & -2.363    & -4.139\tnote{***} & -3.726\tnote{***}
    & -1.945    & -3.949\tnote{**}  & -3.538\tnote{***}
    & -1.671    & -4.131\tnote{***} & -3.608\tnote{***}
    & -1.488    & -3.876\tnote{***} & -3.429\tnote{***}   \\
CAAR (0,2)
    & -3.564    & -4.798\tnote{***} & -3.788\tnote{***}
    & -2.457    & -4.085\tnote{***} & -2.917\tnote{***}
    & -2.151    & -3.777\tnote{***} & -3.098\tnote{***}
    & -1.373    & -3.434\tnote{***} & -2.613\tnote{***}
    & -1.850    & -3.981\tnote{***} & -3.502\tnote{***}   \\
CAAR (0,3)
    & -3.142    & -4.260\tnote{***}   & -2.801\tnote{***}
    & -2.146    & -3.517\tnote{***}   & -2.306\tnote{**}
    & -1.642    & -3.248\tnote{***}   & -1.799\tnote{*}
    & -1.084    & -2.806\tnote{***}   & -1.833\tnote{*}
    & -1.377    & -3.196\tnote{***}   & -2.385\tnote{**}    \\
    \midrule
AAR $t=-4$
    & -1.135    & -1.849\tnote{*}   & -2.099\tnote{**}
    & -0.212    & -0.3415           & -0.2107
    &  0.247    & 0.320             & 0.394
    & -0.094    & -0.234            & 0.321
    & 0.382     & 1.0119            & 0.5596            \\
AAR $t=-3$
    & -0.115    & -0.419            & -0.661
    & -0.617    & -1.1973           & -1.7026\tnote{*}
    & -0.385    & -0.787            & -1.101
    & -0.376    & -0.373            & -1.177
    & -0.083    & -0.4750           & -0.8070           \\
AAR $t=-2$
    & 0.244     & 0.447             & 0.596
    & -0.062    & -0.4925           & -0.7548
    & -0.017    & -0.309            & -0.266
    & 0.881     & 0.920             & 0.990
    & -0.165    & 0.3877            & 0.2975            \\
AAR $t=-1$
    & -0.482    & -0.535            & -0.405
    & -0.887    & -1.4222           & -1.9085\tnote{*}
    &  0.277    & 0.864             & 0.719
    & -0.401    & -0.614            & -1.274
    & -0.524    & -0.4793           & -0.6727           \\
    \addlinespace
AAR $t=0$
    & -1.115    & -2.116\tnote{**}  & -2.318\tnote{**}
    & -1.493    & -3.1289\tnote{***}& -3.1177\tnote{***}
    & -1.273    & -2.918\tnote{***} & -2.485\tnote{**}
    & -0.555    & -1.209            & -1.638
    & -0.616    & -1.3734           & -1.2371           \\
AAR $t=1$
    & -0.495    & -0.669            & -0.992
    & -0.309    & -0.4984           & -0.3547
    & -0.860    & -2.054\tnote{**}  & -1.933\tnote{*}
    & -0.352    & -1.081            & -1.334
    & -0.519    & -1.6522\tnote{*}  & -2.7110\tnote{***}\\
AAR $t=2$
    & -0.710    & -1.163            & -1.146
    & -0.145    & -0.1485           & -0.4728
    & -0.875    & -1.935\tnote{*}   & -1.902\tnote{*}
    &  0.411    & -0.039            &  0.121
    &  0.267    &  0.1748           &  0.0997           \\
AAR $t=3$
    & -0.342    & -0.323            & -0.400
    & -0.530    & -0.6798           & -1.2340
    &  0.637    & 1.746\tnote{*}    &  1.853\tnote{*}
    &  0.243    & 0.968             &  1.198
    & -0.052    & -0.0750           &  0.1614           \\
AAR $t=4$
    &  0.504    &  0.559            &  0.328
    &  0.539    &  0.5010           &  1.2036
    &  0.115    & -0.198            &  0.104
    & -0.260    & -0.489            & -1.347
    & -0.292    & -0.119            & -1.0051           \\
AAR $t=5$
    &  0.057    &  0.044            &  0.113
    & -0.334    & -0.2017           & -0.2486
    &  0.096    &  0.314            &  0.456
    & -0.292    & -0.799            & -0.706
    &  0.527    & 0.9427            & 0.6138            \\
    \addlinespace
CAAR (0,1)
    & -1.610    & -2.456\tnote{**}  & -2.122\tnote{**}
    & -1.802    & -3.1488\tnote{***}& -2.4675\tnote{**}
    & -2.133    & -4.181\tnote{***} & -3.412\tnote{***}
    & -0.906    & -1.917\tnote{*}   & -1.934\tnote{*}
    & -1.135    & -2.4604\tnote{**} & -2.0202\tnote{**} \\
CAAR (0,2)
    & -2.320    & -2.998\tnote{***} & -2.337\tnote{**}
    & -1.946    & -3.2157\tnote{***}& -2.3403\tnote{**}
    & -3.007    & -5.243\tnote{***} & -3.947\tnote{***}
    & -0.495    & -1.975\tnote{**}  & -1.357
    & -0.868    & -2.2250\tnote{**} & -1.4954           \\
CAAR (0,3)
    & -2.662    & -4.523\tnote{***} & -3.343\tnote{***}
    & -2.476    & -3.6533\tnote{***}& -2.5696\tnote{**}
    & -2.370    & -4.318\tnote{***} & -2.552\tnote{**}
    & -0.252    & -1.505            & -0.335
    & -0.920    & -2.1720\tnote{**} & -1.4584           \\
    \midrule
AAR $t=-5$
    & -0.057    & -0.297            & -0.321
    & -0.075    & -0.048            & -0.012
    & -0.284    & -0.544            & -0.407
    & -0.152    & -0.120            & 0.054
    &  0.105    &  0.616            & 0.696             \\
AAR $t=-4$
    & -0.401    & -0.530            & -0.281
    &  0.018    &  0.218            & 0.550
    & 0.048     &  0.112            & -0.106
    &  0.315    &  0.643            &  0.747
    &  0.217    &  0.711            &  0.894            \\
AAR $t=-3$
    & -0.790    & -1.211            & -1.455
    & -1.178    & -2.516\tnote{**}  & -2.659\tnote{***}
    & -0.753    & -1.424            & -1.850\tnote{*}
    & -0.236    & -0.789            & -0.988
    & -0.519    & -1.810\tnote{*}   & -1.991\tnote{**} \\
AAR $t=-2$
    & -0.167    & -0.348            & -0.441
    & -0.067    & -0.140            &  0.082
    &  0.074    &  0.045            &  0.069
    & -0.427    & -1.072            & -0.866
    & 0.238     &  0.792            &  0.872            \\
AAR $t=-1$
    & -0.165    & -0.371            & -0.069
    & -0.362    & -0.870            & -0.942
    & -0.155    & -0.417            & -0.150
    & -0.041    & -0.255            & -0.688
    &  0.152    & 0.333             &  0.271            \\
    \addlinespace
AAR $t=0$
    & -2.360    & -4.125\tnote{***} & -4.634\tnote{***}
    & -1.557    & -3.339\tnote{***} & -3.486\tnote{***}
    & -1.432    & -3.420\tnote{***} & -3.727\tnote{***}
    & -0.981    & -2.967\tnote{***} & -3.124\tnote{***}
    & -1.170    & -3.732\tnote{***} & -4.007\tnote{***} \\
AAR $t=1$
    & -0.995    & -1.811\tnote{*}   & -1.768\tnote{*}
    & -0.805    & -1.456            & -1.701\tnote{*}
    & -0.513    & -1.286            & -1.421
    & -0.689    & -1.898\tnote{*}   & -2.040\tnote{**}
    & -0.318    & -0.797            & -1.098            \\
AAR $t=2$
    & -0.209    & -0.430            & -0.412
    & -0.094    & -0.099            &  0.059
    & -0.207    & -0.477            & -0.233
    &  0.297    &  0.639            &  0.745
    & -0.362    & -0.959            & -1.204            \\
AAR $t=3$
    & 0.423     &  0.809            &  0.904
    & 0.311     &  0.405            &  0.750
    &  0.510    &  1.116            &  1.686\tnote{*}
    &  0.28     &  0.916            &  0.839
    &  0.473    &  1.203            &  1.240            \\
AAR $t=4$
    &  0.397    &  0.783            &  0.794
    &  0.118    &  0.255            & -0.139
    &  0.003    & -0.020            & -0.008
    &  0.138    &  0.091            & -0.042
    &  0.083    &  0.274            &  0.273            \\
AAR $t=5$
    & -0.412    & -0.565            & -0.634
    &  0.347    &  0.698            &  0.420
    & -0.095    & -0.443            & -0.319
    &  0.101    &  0.321            &  0.430
    &  0.105    &  0.404            &  0.412            \\
    \addlinespace
CAAR (0,1)
    & -3.356    & -5.009\tnote{***} & -4.329\tnote{***}
    & -2.363    & -4.139\tnote{***} & -3.726\tnote{***}
    & -1.945    & -3.949\tnote{***} & -3.538\tnote{***}
    & -1.671    & -4.131\tnote{***} & -3.608\tnote{***}
    & -1.488    & -3.876\tnote{***} & -3.429\tnote{***} \\
CAAR (0,2)
    & -3.564    & -4.780\tnote{***} & -3.788\tnote{***}
    & -2.457    & -4.085\tnote{***} & -2.917\tnote{***}
    & -2.151    & -3.777\tnote{***} & -3.098\tnote{***}
    & -1.373    & -3.434\tnote{***} & -2.613\tnote{***}
    & -1.850    & -3.981\tnote{***} & -3.502\tnote{***} \\
CAAR (0,3)
    & -3.142    & -4.260\tnote{***} & -2.801\tnote{***}
    & -2.146    & -3.517\tnote{***} & -2.306\tnote{**}
    & -1.642    & -3.248\tnote{***} & -1.799\tnote{*}
    & -1.084    & -2.806\tnote{***} & -1.833\tnote{*}
    & -1.377    & -3.196\tnote{***} & -2.385\tnote{**}  \\    
    \midrule
AAR $t=-5$
    & -0.030    & 0.051                 &  0.158
    & 0.094     & 0.493                 &  0.466
    &  0.117    & 0.426                 &  0.264
    &  0.159    & 0.503                 &  0.495
    &  0.185    & 0.812                 &  0.696            \\
AAR $t=-4$
    & -0.824    & -1.096                & -1.137
    & -0.028    & 0.043                 &  0.058
    & -0.118    & -0.003                &  0.147
    &  0.209    & 0.915                 &  0.984
    &  0.286    & 0.903                 &  0.745            \\
AAR $t=-3$
    & -0.909    & -1.550                & -1.682\tnote{*}
    & -0.546    & -1.292                & -1.368
    & -0.513    & -1.378                & -1.352
    & -0.388    & -1.103                & -1.383
    & -0.499    & -1.784\tnote{*}       & -1.812            \\
AAR $t=-2$
    &  0.192    &  0.246                &  0.240
    &  0.098    &  0.213                &  0.016
    &  0.111    &  0.053                &  0.097
    &  0.134    &  0.189                &  0.130
    & -0.037    &  0.118                &  0.089            \\
AAR $t=-1$
    &  0.015    & -0.004                & -0.155
    &  0.027    &  0.147                &  0.094
    &  0.046    & -0.097                & -0.242
    & -0.080    & -0.312                & -0.453
    & -0.131    & -0.717                & -0.826            \\
    \addlinespace
AAR $t=0$
    & -2.412    & -4.259\tnote{***} & -4.268\tnote{***}
    & -1.593    & -2.905\tnote{***} & -3.371\tnote{***}
    & -1.292    & -2.573\tnote{**}  & -3.202\tnote{***}
    & -1.246    & -3.517\tnote{***} & -3.689\tnote{***}
    & -1.395    & -3.470\tnote{***} & -3.989\tnote{***}     \\
AAR $t=1$
    & -1.151    & -1.846\tnote{*}   & -1.898\tnote{*}
    & -0.807    & -1.999\tnote{**}  & -2.186\tnote{**}
    & -0.463    & -1.420            & -1.680\tnote{*}
    & -0.221    & -0.775            & -0.878
    & -0.305    & -0.977            & -0.948                \\
AAR $t=2$
    & -0.858    & -1.430            & -1.358
    & -0.494    & -0.812            & -0.765
    & -0.284    & -0.556            & -0.526
    & -0.150    & -0.489            & -0.525
    & -0.333    & -0.833            & -0.652                \\
AAR $t=3$
    &  0.755    &  0.872            &  1.202
    &  0.942    &  1.934\tnote{*}   &  1.950\tnote{*}
    &  0.300    &  0.657            &  1.143
    &  0.514    &  1.306            &  1.580
    & 0.553     & 1.379             &  1.264                \\
AAR $t=4$
    & -0.192    & -0.083            &  0.080
    & -0.122    & -0.354            & -0.367
    &  0.165    &  0.409            &  0.419
    & -0.163    & -0.547            & -0.677
    & -0.129    & -0.363            & -0.392                \\
AAR $t=5$
    & 0.094     & 0.316             & 0.372
    & 0.232     & 0.553             & 0.567
    &  0.152    & 0.434             & 0.483
    &  0.059    & 0.086             & 0.121
    &  0.154    & 0.351             & 0.280                 \\
    \addlinespace
CAAR (0,1)
    & -3.563    & -4.873\tnote{***} & -4.356\tnote{***}
    & -2.399    & -3.985\tnote{***} & -3.929\tnote{***}
    & -1.755    & -3.119\tnote{***} & -3.393\tnote{***}
    & -1.466    & -3.559\tnote{***} & -3.223\tnote{***}
    & -1.700    & -3.606\tnote{***} & -3.393\tnote{***}     \\
CAAR (0,2)
    & -4.421    & -4.920\tnote{***} & -4.376\tnote{***}
    & -2.893    & -3.866\tnote{***} & -3.594\tnote{***}
    & -2.039    & -3.071\tnote{***} & -3.126\tnote{***}
    & -1.616    & -3.581\tnote{***} & -2.941\tnote{***}
    & -2.034    & -3.785\tnote{***} & -3.200\tnote{***}     \\
CAAR (0,3)
    & -3.666    & -4.083\tnote{***} & -3.206\tnote{***}
    & -1.95     & -2.932\tnote{***} & -2.171\tnote{**}
    & -1.739    & -2.574\tnote{**}  & -2.119\tnote{**}
    & -1.102    & -2.970\tnote{***} & -1.794\tnote{*}
    & -1.481    & -3.166\tnote{***} & -2.065\tnote{**}      \\    
    \midrule
AAR $t=-5$
    &  0.347    &  0.7954           &  0.9103
    &  0.231    &  0.758            &  0.931
    &  0.261    &  0.926            &  0.940
    & 0.484     &  1.282            &  1.378
    &  0.319    &  0.739            &  0.757                \\
AAR $t=-4$
    & -0.530    & -0.8836           & -0.8140
    & -0.074    &  0.043            &  0.071
    & -0.090    &  0.120            &  0.158
    &  0.095    & 0.585                 &  0.544
    &  0.161    & 0.426                 &  0.322            \\
AAR $t=-3$
    & -1.067    & -1.8923\tnote{*}      & -1.7895\tnote{*}
    & -0.459    & -1.038                & -1.008
    & -0.369    & -0.918                & -1.047
    & -0.386    & -0.972                & -0.975
    & -0.541    & -1.751\tnote{*}       & -2.002\tnote{**}  \\
AAR $t=-2$
    &  0.113    &  0.1599               &  0.0874
    &  0.200    &  0.502                & 0.460
    &  0.320    &  0.694                & 0.601
    &  0.267    &  0.552                & 0.664
    &  0.293    &  0.662                & 0.580             \\
AAR $t=-1$
    &  0.046    &  0.1383               & 0.0040
    & -0.300    & -0.880                & -0.935
    &  0.042    &  0.095                & -0.135
    & -0.071    & -0.162                & -0.347
    & -0.200    & -0.318                & -0.233            \\
    \addlinespace
AAR $t=0$
    & -1.855    & -3.7370\tnote{***}    & -3.6594\tnote{***}
    & -1.562    & -3.579\tnote{***}     & -3.841\tnote{***}
    & -1.453    & -3.651\tnote{***}     & -3.786\tnote{***}
    & -1.399    & -3.155\tnote{***}     & -3.624\tnote{***}
    & -1.437    & -3.140\tnote{***}     & -3.486\tnote{***} \\
AAR $t=1$
    & -0.608    & -0.7882               & -0.9071
    & -0.451    & -0.802                & -0.922
    & -0.558    & -1.164                & -1.316
    & -0.171    & -0.402                & -0.475
    & -0.037    &  0.115                &  0.037            \\
AAR $t=2$
    & -0.688    & -0.9848               & -0.9385
    & -0.540    & -0.949                & -1.004
    & -0.418    & -1.008                & -1.189
    & -0.079    & -0.208                & -0.297
    &  0.033    &  0.362                &  0.098            \\
AAR $t=3$
    &  1.175    &  1.6189               &  1.9759\tnote{**}
    &  1.006    &  2.116\tnote{**}      & 2.408\tnote{**}
    &  0.747    & 1.581                 & 1.585
    &  0.678    & 1.556                 & 1.619
    &  0.741    & 1.936\tnote{*}        & 2.177\tnote{**}   \\
AAR $t=4$
    &  0.078    & -0.0290               & -0.1319
    & -0.165    & -0.442                & -0.694
    & -0.073    & -0.278                & -0.262
    & -0.233    & -0.817                & -0.931
    & -0.458    & -1.495                & -1.741            \\
AAR $t=5$
    &  0.527    &  1.1289               &  1.0164
    &  0.274    & 0.814                 &  0.710
    &  0.316    & 0.857                 &  0.865
    &  0.351    & 1.022                 &  1.104
    &  0.134    & 0.552                 &  0.518            \\
    \addlinespace
CAAR (0,1)
    & -2.463    & -3.7047\tnote{***}    & -3.2350\tnote{***}
    & -2.013    & -3.459\tnote{***}     & -3.365\tnote{***}
    & -2.011    & -3.906\tnote{***}     & -3.608\tnote{***}
    & -1.570    & -3.211\tnote{***}     & -2.882\tnote{***}
    & -1.473    & -2.912\tnote{***}     & -2.429\tnote{**}  \\
CAAR (0,2)
    & -3.151    & -3.6286\tnote{***}    & -3.1710\tnote{***}
    & -2.553    & -3.442\tnote{***}     & -3.327\tnote{***}
    & -2.429    & -3.901\tnote{***}     & -3.630\tnote{***}
    & -1.649    & -3.078\tnote{***}     & -2.514\tnote{**}
    & -1.440    & -2.139\tnote{**}      & -1.917\tnote{*}   \\
CAAR (0,3)
    & -1.976    & -2.5754\tnote{**}     & -1.7547\tnote{*}
    & -1.547    & -2.576\tnote{***}     & -1.686\tnote{*}
    & -1.682    & -3.246\tnote{***}     & -2.326\tnote{**}
    & -0.971    & -2.389\tnote{**}      & -1.397
    & -0.699    & -1.351                & -0.580        \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{ThreePartTable}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{landscape}
} % end of afterpage

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

After at least four compilation (of table code with repeated table contents from above MWE) the result is:

page 2:

[image]

page 3:

[image]

page 4:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, much better looking table than min. Also the code is neat.

Comment: @andy, if you liked, you can up-vote or even accept answer (by clicking on the up-triangle and check mark at top left side of answer respectively) :-).

Comment: @andy, now table is complete.

Comment: this is exactly what i was after. it looks perfect. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Probably useful as a place to start from:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\scriptsize}

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{document}

\afterpage{
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}

  \centering
    \begin{longtable}{@{}l *{2}{S[table-format=-1.3] 
                                S[table-format=-1.4,table-space-text-post=\sym{***}, table-align-text-post = false] 
                                S[table-format=-1.4,table-space-text-post=\sym{***}, table-align-text-post = false]} 
                           *{2}{S[table-format=-1.3] 
                                S[table-format=-1.3,table-space-text-post=\sym{***}, table-align-text-post = false] 
                                S[table-format=-1.3,table-space-text-post=\sym{***}, table-align-text-post = false]} 
                           *{1}{S[table-format=-1.3] 
                                S[table-format=-1.4,table-space-text-post=\sym{***}, table-align-text-post = false] 
                                S[table-format=-1.4,table-space-text-post=\sym{***}, table-align-text-post = false]} @{}}
    \caption{caption text here}   \label{tab:test}\\
    \endhead
    \toprule
    & {\textbf{1.1}} & & & {\textbf{1.2}} & & & {\textbf{1.3}} & & & {\textbf{1.4}} & & & {\textbf{1.5}} \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-13} \cmidrule(l){14-16}
       & {\thead{AAR/\\CAAR\\ (\%)}} & {\thead{Obs. \\ Kolari}} & {\thead{292\\ Corrado}}
       & {\thead{AAR/\\CAAR\\ (\%)}} & {\thead{Obs. \\ Kolari}} & {\thead{337\\ Corrado}}
       & {\thead{AAR/\\CAAR\\ (\%)}} & {\thead{Obs. \\ Kolari}} & {\thead{366\\ Corrado}}
       & {\thead{AAR/\\CAAR\\ (\%)}} & {\thead{Obs. \\ Kolari}} & {\thead{327\\ Corrado}}
       & {\thead{AAR/\\CAAR\\ (\%)}} & {\thead{Obs. \\ Kolari}} & {\thead{359\\ Corrado}} \\
    \midrule
    AAR t=-5 & 0.000  & 0.580   & 0.655    & 0.264  & 0.1980  & 0.1095   & -1.558 & -2.100\sym{**} & -2.166\sym{**} & 0.203  & 0.684  & 0.431  & 0.153  & 0.6530  &  1.0161   \\
    AAR t=-4 & -1.135 & -1.849\sym{*} & -2.099\sym{**} & -0.212 & -0.3415 & -0.2107  & 0.247  & 0.320    & 0.394    & -0.094 & -0.234 & 0.321  & 0.382  & 1.0119  & 0.5596    \\
    AAR t=-3 & -0.115 & -0.419  & -0.661   & -0.617 & -1.1973 & -1.7026\sym{*} & -0.385 & -0.787   & -1.101   & -0.376 & -0.373 & -1.177 & -0.083 & -0.4750 & -0.8070   \\
    \midrule
    \end{longtable}%
\end{landscape}
\clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to rotate it with `\landscape` and space it over two pages with `\longtable`. Now i need to include the `\caption`, however i can't figure out where to implement it. I allways get error massages.

````
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}


\afterpage{
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
 
        % default: \fill
      %\setlenth\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}
\setlength\LTleft{-1.5cm}            % default: \parindent
\setlength\LTright{0cm}   
\tiny
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt}

  \centering
    \begin{longtable}{ccclclcclrlrrlrlrrlrlrrlrl}
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1.1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{292} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1.2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 337 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1.3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 366 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1.4}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 327 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 359 &  \\
        & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-5} & 0.000\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.580} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.655} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.264\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.1980} &     & 0.1095 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.558\%} & -2.100 & **  & -2.166 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.203\%} & 0.684 &     & 0.431 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.153\%} & 0.6530 &     & 1.0161 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-4} & -1.135\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.849} & *   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.099} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & -0.212\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.3415} &     & -0.2107 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.247\%} & 0.320 &     & 0.394 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.094\%} & -0.234 &     & 0.321 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.382\%} & 1.0119 &     & 0.5596 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-3} & -0.115\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.419} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.661} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.617\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.1973} &     & -1.7026 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.385\%} & -0.787 &     & -1.101 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.376\%} & -0.373 &     & -1.177 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.083\%} & -0.4750 &     & -0.8070 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-2} & 0.244\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.447} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.596} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.062\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.4925} &     & -0.7548 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.017\%} & -0.309 &     & -0.266 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.881\%} & 0.920 &     & 0.990 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.165\%} & 0.3877 &     & 0.2975 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-1} & -0.482\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.535} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.405} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.887\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.4222} &     & -1.9085 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.277\%} & 0.864 &     & 0.719 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.401\%} & -0.614 &     & -1.274 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.524\%} & -0.4793 &     & -0.6727 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=0} & -1.115\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.116} & **  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.318} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & -1.493\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.1289} & *** & -3.1177 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.273\%} & -2.918 & *** & -2.485 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.555\%} & -1.209 &     & -1.638 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.616\%} & -1.3734 &     & -1.2371 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=1} & -0.495\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.669} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.992} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.309\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.4984} &     & -0.3547 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.860\%} & -2.054 & **  & -1.933 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.352\%} & -1.081 &     & -1.334 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.519\%} & -1.6522 & *   & -2.7110 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=2} & -0.710\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.163} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.146} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.145\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.1485} &     & -0.4728 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.875\%} & -1.935 & *   & -1.902 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.411\%} & -0.039 &     & 0.121 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.267\%} & 0.1748 &     & 0.0997 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=3} & -0.342\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.323} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.400} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.530\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.6798} &     & -1.2340 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.637\%} & 1.746 & *   & 1.853 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.243\%} & 0.968 &     & 1.198 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.052\%} & -0.0750 &     & 0.1614 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=4} & 0.504\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.559} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.328} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.539\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.5010} &     & 1.2036 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.115\%} & -0.198 &     & 0.104 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.260\%} & -0.489 &     & -1.347 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.292\%} & -0.1191 &     & -1.0051 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=5} & 0.057\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.044} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.113} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.334\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.2017} &     & -0.2486 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.096\%} & 0.314 &     & 0.456 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.292\%} & -0.799 &     & -0.706 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.527\%} & 0.9427 &     & 0.6138 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,1)} & -1.610\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.456} & **  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.122} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & -1.802\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.1488} & *** & -2.4675 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.133\%} & -4.181 & *** & -3.412 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.906\%} & -1.917 & *   & -1.934 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.135\%} & -2.4604 & **  & -2.0202 & ** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,2)} & -2.320\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.998} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.337} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & -1.946\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.2157} & *** & -2.3403 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-3.007\%} & -5.243 & *** & -3.947 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.495\%} & -1.975 & **  & -1.357 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.868\%} & -2.2250 & **  & -1.4954 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,3)} & -2.662\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.523} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.343} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.476\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.6533} & *** & -2.5696 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.370\%} & -4.318 & *** & -2.552 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.252\%} & -1.505 &     & -0.335 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.920\%} & -2.1720 & **  & -1.4584 &  \\
    \midrule
    \midrule
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{2.1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{297} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{2.2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 317 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{2.3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 349 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{2.4}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 300 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 326 &  \\
        & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-5} & -0.744\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.322} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.162} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.098\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.139} &     & 0.019 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.412\%} & -0.714 &     & -0.688 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.185\%} & -0.313 &     & -0.537 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.133\%} & 0.778 &     & 1.100 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-4} & -0.512\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.023} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.799} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.265\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.669} &     & -0.424 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.418\%} & 0.708 &     & 0.981 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.110\%} & 0.323 &     & 0.212 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.187\%} & -0.013 &     & -0.208 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-3} & -1.082\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.967} & **  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.051} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & -1.217\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.215} & **  & -1.901 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.975\%} & -1.967 & **  & -2.497 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.839\%} & -1.986 & **  & -1.741 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.289\%} & -1.168 &     & -1.259 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-2} & -0.247\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.346} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.228} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.451\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.132} &     & -1.004 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.021\%} & -0.073 &     & -0.251 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.361\%} & 0.706 &     & 0.483 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.116\%} & -0.002 &     & -0.450 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-1} & -0.932\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.845} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.700} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.095\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.385} &     & 0.108 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.180\%} & -0.061 &     & 0.048 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.230\%} & -0.673 &     & -0.634 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.380\%} & -1.115 &     & -1.160 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=0} & -2.094\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.323} & **  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.073} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -1.754\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.294} & *** & -3.584 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.500\%} & -3.990 & *** & -3.929 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.084\%} & -3.088 & *** & -3.433 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.498\%} & -1.561 &     & -2.139 & ** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=1} & -0.719\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.442} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.605} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.652\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.321} &     & -1.430 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.322\%} & -1.118 &     & -1.251 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.712\%} & -2.227 & **  & -2.238 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.591\%} & -1.410 &     & -1.500 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=2} & -0.884\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.391} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.163} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -1.194\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.050} & **  & -1.796 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.207\%} & -0.375 &     & -0.675 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.178\%} & -0.693 &     & -0.594 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.145\%} & 0.186 &     & -0.323 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=3} & 0.336\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.863} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.874} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.093\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.218} &     & 0.528 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.607\%} & 1.111 &     & 1.444 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.246\%} & 0.678 &     & 0.749 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.523\%} & 1.206 &     & 1.018 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=4} & 0.126\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.408} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.406} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.198\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.438} &     & 0.100 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.089\%} & 0.224 &     & -0.063 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.313\%} & 0.479 &     & 0.600 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.218\%} & 0.798 &     & 0.571 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=5} & -0.416\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.561} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.789} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.037\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.061} &     & -0.104 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.183\%} & -0.297 &     & -0.240 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.133\%} & -0.262 &     & -0.310 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.323\%} & 0.627 &     & 0.235 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,1)} & -2.814\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.085} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.334} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.406\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.992} & *** & -3.566 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.822\%} & -4.267 & *** & -3.594 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.796\%} & -4.433 & *** & -3.902 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.088\%} & -2.314 & **  & -2.564 & ** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,2)} & -3.698\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.369} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.423} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -3.600\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.765} & *** & -3.892 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.029\%} & -4.321 & *** & -3.325 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.974\%} & -4.491 & *** & -3.561 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.943\%} & -2.189 & **  & -2.279 & ** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,3)} & -3.362\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.051} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.747} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -3.508\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.523} & *** & -3.343 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.421\%} & -3.600 & *** & -2.192 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.729\%} & -4.096 & *** & -2.635 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.420\%} & -1.666 & *   & -1.175 &  \\
    \midrule
    \midrule
    \pagebreak
       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{4.1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{331} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{4.2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 367 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{4.3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 388 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{4.4}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 417 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{4.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 369 &  \\
        & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-5} & -0.030\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.051} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.158} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.094\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.493} &     & 0.466 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.117\%} & 0.426 &     & 0.264 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.159\%} & 0.503 &     & 0.495 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.185\%} & 0.812 &     & 0.696 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-4} & -0.824\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.096} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.137} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.028\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.043} &     & 0.058 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.118\%} & -0.003 &     & 0.147 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.209\%} & 0.915 &     & 0.984 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.286\%} & 0.903 &     & 0.745 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-3} & -0.909\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.550} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.682} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & -0.546\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.292} &     & -1.368 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.513\%} & -1.378 &     & -1.352 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.388\%} & -1.103 &     & -1.383 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.499\%} & -1.784 & *   & -1.812 & * \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-2} & 0.192\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.246} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.240} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.098\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.213} &     & 0.016 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.111\%} & 0.053 &     & 0.097 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.134\%} & 0.189 &     & 0.130 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.037\%} & 0.118 &     & 0.089 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-1} & 0.015\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.004} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.155} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.027\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.147} &     & 0.094 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.046\%} & -0.097 &     & -0.242 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.080\%} & -0.312 &     & -0.453 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.131\%} & -0.717 &     & -0.826 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=0} & -2.412\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.259} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.268} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -1.593\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.905} & *** & -3.371 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.292\%} & -2.573 & **  & -3.202 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.246\%} & -3.517 & *** & -3.689 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.395\%} & -3.470 & *** & -3.989 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=1} & -1.151\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.846} & *   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.898} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & -0.807\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.999} & **  & -2.186 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.463\%} & -1.420 &     & -1.680 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.221\%} & -0.775 &     & -0.878 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.305\%} & -0.977 &     & -0.948 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=2} & -0.858\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.430} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.358} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.494\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.812} &     & -0.765 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.284\%} & -0.556 &     & -0.526 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.150\%} & -0.489 &     & -0.525 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.333\%} & -0.833 &     & -0.652 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=3} & 0.755\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.872} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.202} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.942\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.934} & *   & 1.950 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.300\%} & 0.657 &     & 1.143 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.514\%} & 1.306 &     & 1.580 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.553\%} & 1.379 &     & 1.264 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=4} & -0.192\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.083} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.080} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.122\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.354} &     & -0.367 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.165\%} & 0.409 &     & 0.419 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.163\%} & -0.547 &     & -0.677 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.129\%} & -0.363 &     & -0.392 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=5} & 0.094\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.316} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.372} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.232\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.553} &     & 0.567 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.152\%} & 0.434 &     & 0.483 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.059\%} & 0.086 &     & 0.121 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.154\%} & 0.351 &     & 0.280 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,1)} & -3.563\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.873} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.356} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.399\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.985} & *** & -3.929 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.755\%} & -3.119 & *** & -3.393 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.466\%} & -3.559 & *** & -3.223 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.700\%} & -3.606 & *** & -3.393 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,2)} & -4.421\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.920} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.376} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.893\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.866} & *** & -3.594 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.039\%} & -3.071 & *** & -3.126 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.616\%} & -3.581 & *** & -2.941 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.034\%} & -3.785 & *** & -3.200 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,3)} & -3.666\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-4.083} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.206} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -1.951\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.932} & *** & -2.171 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.739\%} & -2.574 & **  & -2.119 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.102\%} & -2.970 & *** & -1.794 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.481\%} & -3.166 & *** & -2.065 & ** \\
    \midrule
    \midrule
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{5.1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{437} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{5.2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 466 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{5.3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 469 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{5.4}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 470 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{5.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations} & 475 &  \\
        & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & AAR/CAAR & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAR/CAAR} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kolari} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Corrado} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-5} & 0.347\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.7954} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.9103} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.231\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.758} &     & 0.931 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.261\%} & 0.926 &     & 0.940 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.484\%} & 1.282 &     & 1.378 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.319\%} & 0.739 &     & 0.757 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-4} & -0.530\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.8836} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.8140} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.074\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.043} &     & 0.071 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.090\%} & 0.120 &     & 0.158 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.095\%} & 0.585 &     & 0.544 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.161\%} & 0.426 &     & 0.322 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-3} & -1.067\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.8923} & *   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.7895} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & -0.459\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.038} &     & -1.008 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.369\%} & -0.918 &     & -1.047 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.386\%} & -0.972 &     & -0.975 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.541\%} & -1.751 & *   & -2.002 & ** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-2} & 0.113\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.1599} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.0874} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.200\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.502} &     & 0.460 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.320\%} & 0.694 &     & 0.601 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.267\%} & 0.552 &     & 0.664 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.293\%} & 0.662 &     & 0.580 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=-1} & 0.046\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.1383} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.0040} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.300\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.880} &     & -0.935 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.042\%} & 0.095 &     & -0.135 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.071\%} & -0.162 &     & -0.347 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.200\%} & -0.318 &     & -0.233 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=0} & -1.855\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.7370} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.6594} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -1.562\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.579} & *** & -3.841 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.453\%} & -3.651 & *** & -3.786 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.399\%} & -3.155 & *** & -3.624 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.437\%} & -3.140 & *** & -3.486 & *** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=1} & -0.608\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.7882} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.9071} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.451\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.802} &     & -0.922 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.558\%} & -1.164 &     & -1.316 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.171\%} & -0.402 &     & -0.475 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.037\%} & 0.115 &     & 0.037 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=2} & -0.688\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.9848} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.9385} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.540\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.949} &     & -1.004 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.418\%} & -1.008 &     & -1.189 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.079\%} & -0.208 &     & -0.297 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.033\%} & 0.362 &     & 0.098 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=3} & 1.175\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.6189} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.9759} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & 1.006\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{2.116} & **  & 2.408 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.747\%} & 1.581 &     & 1.585 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.678\%} & 1.556 &     & 1.619 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.741\%} & 1.936 & *   & 2.177 & ** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=4} & 0.078\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.0290} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.1319} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & -0.165\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.442} &     & -0.694 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.073\%} & -0.278 &     & -0.262 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.233\%} & -0.817 &     & -0.931 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.458\%} & -1.495 &     & -1.741 & * \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AAR t=5} & 0.527\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.1289} &     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.0164} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 0.274\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.814} &     & 0.710 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.316\%} & 0.857 &     & 0.865 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.351\%} & 1.022 &     & 1.104 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.134\%} & 0.552 &     & 0.518 &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,1)} & -2.463\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.7047} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.2350} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.013\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.459} & *** & -3.365 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.011\%} & -3.906 & *** & -3.608 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.570\%} & -3.211 & *** & -2.882 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.473\%} & -2.912 & *** & -2.429 & ** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,2)} & -3.151\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.6286} & *** & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.1710} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & -2.553\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.442} & *** & -3.327 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-2.429\%} & -3.901 & *** & -3.630 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.649\%} & -3.078 & *** & -2.514 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.440\%} & -2.139 & **  & -1.917 & * \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CAAR (0,3)} & -1.976\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.5754} & **  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.7547} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & -1.547\% & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.576} & *** & -1.686 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.682\%} & -3.246 & *** & -2.326 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.971\%} & -2.389 & **  & -1.397 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.699\%} & -1.351 &     & -0.580 &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{*** 1\% significance} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ ** 5\% significance} &     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{* 10\% significance} &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &  \\
    \end{longtable}%
  \label{tab:test}%

\end{landscape}
\clearpage
\end{document}
}```
````

Comment: Longtable incorporates the (custom) caption inside.  You have the choice of putting in the first head, every head, every foot  or even the last foot.